# How to Check the rows exist in mysql database with Group_Concat()

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have a table named group_members, where I am inserting user_id(FK from users) with group_id(FK from groups). Now, When I am creating a group I am trying to check whether group is already created with selected users or not.

Now I can get true/false based on group_id from group_members by matching users with group_concat() by group_id. My query is like this

```
select if(group_concat(cgm.`user_id`) = '35237512,640664658',cgm.group_id,false) as  _return from group_members cgm
INNER JOIN groups cg ON
cgm.`group_id` = cg.`group_id` 
    where   cg.`created_by` = 388567678 group by cgm.group_id
```

Now I am trying to get only the row which match with the users I am sending.

So I can avoid calling two stored procedures or having loops.

Thanks in advance.